# Eigen Matrix library complement of a block operation

Tags: c++, indexing, eigen

is there a compact/nice/efficient way to perform a "complement of a block" operation. Meaning say I want to extract a block of 10 rows from a matrix M starting from row 3 we can do something like:

```
  Eigen::MatrixXd myBlock = M.block(3,0,10,M.cols());
```

but what I am trying to extract is "all rows but those 10 rows". That is from row 0 to 2 and then from rows 13 to the end. Is this possible ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible directly, but you can easily concatenate two blocks together:

```
// result must be allocated to the correct size before concatenating:
Eigen::MatrixXd myComplement(M.rows()-10, M.cols());
myComplement << M.topRows<3>(), M.bottomRows(M.rows()-13);
```

N.B.:
Instead of `M.block(3,0,10,M.cols())` you can write `M.middleRows<3>(10)`.

Comment: seems like it is failing if the block of 10 that we want to exclude is first 10 rows. i.e. myComplement << M.topRows<0>(), M.bottomRows(M.rows()-10); fails

Comment: If it does not work with `topRows<0>()` you should update your Eigen version. It works with the most recent 3.2 and 3.3 versions.